# How to remove ems from TextView programatically?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

Having a TextView in layout xml with ems width as 8,

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/more"
   android:ems="8"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@color/popup_grey"
   android:drawableLeft="@drawable/dot_small"
   android:text="@string/get_more" />
```

I need to remove that `ems` from `TextView dynamically` on certain condition. I tried with `view.setEms(0)`, but obviously it `shrinks` the TextView width to `0`.

Is there any piece of code to remove it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried setting the width to match parent?

Comment: No, then ems will have no job

Comment: *on a certain condition* you want the ems to go away. Then, programatically set the width to match parent.

Comment: Thanks @little child, let me try

Answer (score 2):

Try `setMinEms` and `setMaxEms`

If you want to remove `setEms(8)`, just set max `ems` to a big value.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
setMinWidth(0)
setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
```

This will remove ems.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
view.setEms(0)
```

But at the same time put the `width` of your `textView` to `match_parent`? This way it won't shrink your `textView`.

Hope it helps you. Good luck.